# How to create object of an application..For non office application

Tags: excel, object, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to control(Copying/pasting text etc.) an application installed in my PC. I wrote below code to first create the object of the application and then was planning on to use its properties/methods but unfortunately its throwing **Run Time Error '429': ActivX control can't cerate object**.

```
Sub Run_App()

Dim TrialObj as Object

'Path where .exe file resides: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dynamic Connect\dconnect.exe"

Set TrialObj = CreateObject("dconnect.application")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the application has properties and methods that can be exposed to Excel?
Simply going by the name of your procedure, it looks like you are simply trying to open the application here, so one alternative would be to shell the application and then use VBA to activate the appropriate window and then copy and paste.
It has been a good many years since I did this, but I did do something similar when capturing data from a mainframe window and pasting it into word, with all the applicable driving code being in the Word document, so it is doable in this way, though probably not the neatest way of doing it